# apache redirect from non www to www

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a website that doesn't seem to redirect from non-www to www.

*My Apache configuration is as follows:*

```
RewriteEngine On
### re-direct to www
RewriteCond %{http_host} !^www.example.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: For a `.htaccess` based solution I suggest an answer that has been posed on the diametral question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5262044/367456

Comment: this is good, it does add a slash to the url though, so lose the slash before the dollar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)

Answer (score 563, accepted):

Using the rewrite engine is a pretty heavyweight way to solve this problem. Here is a simpler solution:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    # real server configuration
</VirtualHost>
```

And then you'll have another [`<VirtualHost>`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/) section with `ServerName www.example.com` for your real server configuration. Apache automatically preserves anything after the `/` when using the [`Redirect` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect), which is a common misconception about why this method won't work (when in fact it does).

Comment: How do you do it for a site that has an ssl virtual host as well?

Comment: I get the error "The webpage at example.com has resulted in too many redirects" when using this suggestion. Do others have this problem?

Comment: Gosh you rock, and so does Duck Duck Go for showing this at the top. Google fail :/

Comment: I found this page first, using Google. Thanks for the answer, it's a really easy and efficient way to do it.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill Can you provide similar solution for redirecting from www to now-www please?

Comment: @BlackDivine: There's nothing magical about doing it in the other direction. Simply swap `www.example` and `example` wherever they appear in the sample.

Comment: @Shabbyrobe I would assume:
```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Does it make sense to put example.com besides www.example.com into the hosts file for faster resolution?

Comment: @JonathanBerger If you too many redirects, then you have probably not configured well the file. Make sure to have 2 VirtualHosts: one with non-www which is the above and the other with ServerName www.example.com which has the real configuration. Also make sure to have not a redirect in www.example.com configuration as well (both mod_alias and mod_rewrite).

Comment: For a virtual host server, say example.com, I have `Redirect 301 / http://example2.com/extra/` but when it redirects, it misses the trailing slash, meaning that `example.com/blah` goes to `example2.com/extrablah`.  Any ideas?  (Apache 2.2.22)

Comment: @Peter Howe: the `VirtualHost` block with ServerName set to example.com and containing the redirect should come after the one with the www.example.com domain name to avoid that.

Comment: For SSL, you may refer to [https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL).

Comment: Why use <VirtualHost> when a simple If/Redirect in your .htaccess file will suffice? (as per http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html#setenv)

Comment: Never mind, I think I know: in a domestic server for one domain only it wouldn't make a difference, but in a web server for millions of pages the default host won't point to your `DocumentRoot`, right?

Comment: @AndréNeves by the way, for server speed it would be better to do away with all `.htaccess` files completely and keep all apache directives in configuration files instead. Here's an explanation of how demanding AllowOverride is (https://servercheck.in/blog/3-small-tweaks-make-apache-fly).

Comment: @ButtleButkus yeah, not viable for web hosting, though.

Comment: So this is a solution only for ppl having access to the server files right? Because I can't just put it in the .htaccess file.

Comment: The disadvantage of this is that it requires two virtualhosts, whereas using mod_rewrite only requires the one.

Comment: Solution works but when using custom Access and Error logs they will need to be set inside both Virtual Hosts or else Apache will be keeping logs for the non-www (or the www depending on your setup) version of the site at the '/var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log' file

Comment: Great solution as long as you have access to the virtual host configuration. Not useful for most shared hosting environments, unfortunately.

Comment: very cool. I'd add the *443 config...I had to do both :) Thanks for this

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.co.in
    Redirect 301 / http://www.example.co.in/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.co.in
    #ServerAlias www.example.co.in 
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example
    <Directory /var/www/html/example/>
        Options -Indexes
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
It is giving error : ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. Please help where I did mistake.

Comment: @tirdadc thanks for that comment about the ordering of virtual hosts. Is there any documentation about that?!

Comment: How can i redirect permanently https://example.com to https://www.example.com @GregHewgill

Comment: How do you reverse it? Apparently changing the document doesn't change the redirect

Answer (score 118):

`http://example.com/subdir/?lold=13666` => `http://www.example.com/subdir/?lold=13666`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Oh that's neat, this can be included in the server config at the top level (and if so) will apply to every virtual host!

Comment: Hello @burzumko how do you achieve this, which is true for all without www, but then let, say `example.com/subdi1/ws/* ` go through without www ?

Comment: I used this solution for HTTPS virtual hosts too. Just add an `s` to http in the third row.

Comment: Clean and neat solution!!!

Comment: Great! This solution works for my LetsEncrypt SSL Connections with Certbot!

Answer (score 56):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias example.com
    RedirectMatch permanent ^/(.*) http://www.example.com/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me; it caused an infinite redirect loop to the same site

Comment: @dmiller309: Do you happen to have included `www.` in the `ServerAlias`?

Comment: You're right, I accidentally put www. in the ServerAlias using the *. wildcard. Because I messed up the ordering of the VirtualHost entries, the *. wildcard had the opportunity to match when I didn't think it would.

Comment: This is the best answer, because it's clean, keeps the path (unlike answer #1) and doesn't use Rewrite.

Answer (score 35):

To remove `www` from your `URL` website use this code in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1$1 [R=301,L]
```

To force `www` in your website `URL` use this code on `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^YourSite.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourSite.com/$1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^./]+)$ /$1.html [R=301,L]
```

Where `YourSite.com` must be replaced with your `URL`.

Comment: Best answer here, as it work for website with multiple domain names <3

Comment: What is the second part with the .html for??

Comment: Remove slash before $1 to don't have double slash (//) after redirect => RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourSite.com$1 [R=301]

Answer (score 25):

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot "what/ever/root/to/source"
       ServerName www.example.com

       <Directory "what/ever/root/to/source">
         Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes ExecCGI
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         allow from all
         <What Ever Rules You Need.>
      </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName example.com
      ServerAlias *.example.com
      Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/
    </VirtualHost>
```

This is what happens with the code above. The first virtual host block checks if the request is www.example.com and runs your website in that directory.

Failing which, it comes to the second virtual host section. Here anything other than www.example.com is redirected to www.example.com.

The order here matters. If you add the second virtualhost directive first, it will cause a redirect loop.

This solution will redirect any request to your domain, to www.yourdomain.com.

Cheers!

Answer (score 19):

Redirection code for both non-www => www and opposite www => non-www. No hardcoding domains and schemes in .htaccess file. So origin domain and http/https version will be preserved.

### **APACHE 2.4 AND NEWER**

NON-WWW => WWW:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

WWW => NON-WWW:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Note: not working on Apache 2.2 where %{REQUEST_SCHEME} is not available. For compatibility with Apache 2.2 use code below or replace %{REQUEST_SCHEME} with fixed http/https.

---

### **APACHE 2.2 AND NEWER**

NON-WWW => WWW:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

... or shorter version ...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|offs
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

WWW => NON-WWW:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

... shorter version not possible because %N is available only from last RewriteCond ...

Comment: Apache 2.4 config fixed the issue, thanks for the clean answer..!!

Answer (score 16):

This is similar to many of the other suggestions with a couple enhancements:

- No need to hardcode the domain (works with vhosts that accept multiple domains or between environments)
- Preserves the scheme (http/https) and ignores the effects of previous `%{REQUEST_URI}` rules.
- The path portion not affected by previous `RewriteRule`s like `%{REQUEST_URI}` is.

  ```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
  ```

Comment: Almost perfect. It must be %{HTTP_HOST}$1, not %{HTTP_HOST}/$1 (or it will double the slash)

Comment: @Michael Wyraz: Does not double the slash here?!

Answer (score 10):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^!example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This starts with the `HTTP_HOST` variable, which contains just the domain name portion of the incoming URL (`example.com`). Assuming the domain name does not contain a `www.` and matches your domain name exactly, then the RewriteRule comes into play. The pattern `^(.*)$` will match everything in the `REQUEST_URI`, which is the resource requested in the HTTP request (`foo/blah/index.html`).  It stores this in a back reference, which is then used to rewrite the URL with the new domain name (one that starts with `www`).

`[NC]` indicates case-insensitive pattern matching, `[R=301]` indicates an external redirect using code 301 (resource moved permanently), and `[L]` stops all further rewriting, and redirects immediately.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Apache 2.4 ,without the need to enable the rewrite apache module you can use something like this:

```
# non-www to www
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} = 'domain.com'">
  Redirect 301 "/" "http://www.domain.com/"
</If>
```

Comment: Underrated answer. Using this, additional vhosts can be avoided which is good for automated Let'sEncrypt scripts.

Comment: Plus, if you are using ANSIBLE, since ANSIBLE 2.0 you can now easily insert a block into a file in one task, more details here https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/blockinfile_module.html

Answer (score 5):

I ran this...

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.*$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^/.+www\/(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I need this to be universal for 25+ domains on our new server, so this directive is in my virtual.conf file in a <Directory> tag. (dir is parent to all docroots)

I had to do a bit of a hack on the rewrite rule though, as the full docroot was being carried through on the pattern match, despite what http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html says about it only being stuff after the host and port.

Answer (score 3):

## Redirect domain.tld to www.

The following lines can be added either in Apache directives or in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

- Other sudomains are still working.
- No need to adjust the lines. just copy/paste them at the right place.

Don't forget to apply the apache changes if you modify the vhost.

*(based on the default Drupal7 .htaccess but should work in many cases)*

Answer (score 3):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias example.com
    RedirectMatch permanent ^/(.*) http://www.example.com/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

This will redirect not only the domain name but also the inner
 pages.like...
 example.com/abcd.html               **==>**    www.example.com/abcd.html
 example.com/ab/cd.html?ef=gh   **==>**    www.example.com/ab/cd.html?ef=gh

Comment: Thanks for this. Very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

This is simple!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com$1 [R=301]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Do not always use `Redirect permanent` (or why it may cause issues in future)**

If there is a chance that you will add subdomains later, do not use `redirect permanent`.

Because if a client has used a subdomain that wasn't registred as `VirtualHost` he may also never reach this subdomain even when it is registred later.

`redirect permanent` sends an `HTTP 301 Moved Permanently` to the client (browser) and a lot of them cache this response for ever (until cache is cleared [manually]). So using that subdomain will always autoredirect to www.*** without requesting the server again.

see [How long do browsers cache HTTP 301s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/how-long-do-browsers-cache-http-301s)

**So just use `Redirect`**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com

  Redirect / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

[Apache.org - When not to use mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect)

[Apache.org - Canonical Hostnames](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html#canonicalhost)

Answer (score 2):

-If you host multiple domain names (Optional)

-If all those domain names are using https (as they should)

-if you want all those domain names to use www dot domainName

This will avoid doble redirection (http://non www to http://www and then to https://www)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%1$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

And

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

You should change the redirection code 301 to the most convenient one

Answer (score 2):

To 301 redirect all requests made directly to the domain to www you can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([^.]+\.[^.]+){2,}$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The benefit of this is that this will work if you have any valid subdomains, e.g.

example.com REDIRECTED TO [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

foo.example.com NO REDIRECT

bar.example.com NO REDIRECT

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]`

check this perfect work

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load only the https version of www, use the below configurations in apache virtual host file. all these can have in a single file.

redirecting all http to https of www:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

redirecting https non-www to https www:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

real server configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin hostmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/your/sites/.htaccess-file-folder"
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "production"

    <Directory "/path/to/your/sites/.htaccess-file-folder">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ServerName www.example.com
    
    SSLEngine ON
    SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/your/example.cert.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/your/example.key.pem"

    ErrorLog /path/to/your/example.com-error.log
    CustomLog /path/to/your/example.com-access.log combined
    #Your other configurations if you have
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

If using the above solution of two `<VirtualHost *:80>` blocks with different `ServerName`s...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

... then you **must set `NameVirtualHost On` as well**.

If you don't do this, Apache doesn't allow itself to use the different `ServerName`s to distinguish the blocks, so you get this error message:

```
[warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence
```

...and either no redirection happens, or you have an infinite redirection loop, depending on which block you put first.

Answer (score 0):

*The code I use is:*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just have a same problem. 
But solved with this

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]`

This rule redirecting non-www to www.

And this rule to redirecting www to non-www

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^my-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Refer from  http://dense13.com/blog/2008/02/27/redirecting-non-www-to-www-with-htaccess/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar task on a WP Multisite, where the redirection rule had to be generic (for any given domain I'd add to the network). I solved first adding a wildcard to the domain (parked domain). Note the . after .com.

```
CNAME * domain.com.
```

And then I added the following lines to the .htaccess file at the root of my multisite. I guess it'd work for any site.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Hopefully this will help.

ps. If you'd like to redirect from not www to www, change the last line into

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www.domain.com).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.domain.com$1  [R=301,L]
```

I use the look-ahead pattern `(?!www.domain.com)` to exclude the `www` subdomain when redirecting all domains to the `www` subdomain in order to avoid an infinite redirect loop in Apache.

Answer (score 0):

This is my own site's configuration, and works like a charm.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@domain.com

    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAlias domain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain

    <Directory /var/www/html/domain/>
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Redirect non-www to www
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

I found it easier (and more usefull) to use ServerAlias when using multiple vhosts.

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    ....
</VirtualHost>
```

This also works with https vhosts.

Comment: Another drive-by downvote. Care to explain, oh mighty god of httpd who couldn't be bothered to explain the downvote?

Comment: This makes it so that you have multiple domains hosting the same site. Depending on your situations and what your underlying webserver is running you're going to have issues with cookies not carrying over, people confused, and search engine problems (which will see this as 2 different sites).