# redirect from example.com at www.example.com

Tags: django

Maybe this is a stupid question.

In php application I used to insert properly htaccess in home directory that redirect from example.com at www.example.com.

But with django how I have to do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285879/how-do-i-redirect-domain-com-to-www-domain-com-under-django).

Also a [quote from Django documentation:](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#prepend-www)

> [PREPEND_WWW](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#prepend-www) Default: False
>
> Whether to prepend the "www."
>   subdomain to URLs that don't have it.
>   This is only used if CommonMiddleware
>   is installed (see Middleware). See
>   also [APPEND_SLASH](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash).