# How can i redirect from one domain to another in django app?

Tags: django, redirect

Normally i would do it with `.htaccess` but django doesn't have it.

So what is the best way and what is the code for it to redirect from www.olddomain.com to www.newdomain.com?

NOTE: we are not using Apache, but Gunicorn

thanx!

Answer (score 6):

The best way to do this is still with your web server rather than Django. This will be much quicker and more efficient than doing it with Django.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285879/how-do-i-redirect-domain-com-to-www-domain-com-under-django) for more info.

UPDATE

If you really want to do it within django then edit your url conf file (which manages [django's url dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/)) to include the following at the top -

```
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to

urlpatterns = patterns('',   
    (r'^.*$', redirect_to, {'url': 'http://www.newdomain.com'}),
)
```

For more info check out the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-redirect-to).

Comment: Unfortunately we are not using apache so i can use .htaccess, but `http://gunicorn.org/` instead

Comment: So you should redirect with gunicorn (I would be very surprised if it didn't provide that functionality). otherwise edit the wsgi script as described in the question I linked to.

Comment: The suggestions in the question I linked to are better. However I've updated my answer to include an easy to implement solution.

Comment: You shouldn't use gunicorn as a frontend webserver, it should be behind a proxy webserver like Apache or Nginx.

Comment: For django 1.9 check [RedirectView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview)

Answer (score 4):

```
import urlparse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

domain = request.GET['domain'] 
destination = reverse('variable_response',args=['Successful'])
full_address = urlparse.urljoin(domain, destination)
return HttpResponseRedirect(full_address)
```

Comment: do you know where should i put this?

Comment: in views.py and make url for that

Comment: But i want to redirect the whole site, not just one single page

Comment: then put condition for that site through their view, it's simple

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem so i wrote this and it worked perfectly for me, maybe someone else needs it too:

```
urlpatterns += [  # redirect to media server with same path
url(r'^media/', redirectMedia),
]
```

and using this function to redirect:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from django.http import HttpResponse
def redirectMedia(request):
    x = urlopen("http://www.newdomain.com" + request.path)
    return HttpResponse(x.read())
```

enjoy it!

Answer (score 1):

For Django >= `2.0` , the easier solution is to use [RedirectView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview)

For example in `urls.py` :

```py
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
    path('my_ext_uri', RedirectView.as_view(url='https://YOUR_EXTERNAL_URL')),
]
```

[Side note]

As mentioned in Aidan's answer , it would be better to redirect requests which will be handled by different services at web server gateway, rather than at (Python/Django) application server.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it using heroku and spinning up 1 web dyno (which is free).

```
#views.py
def redirect(request):
    return render_to_response('redirect.html')

#redirect.html
<html>
<head>
<title>Blah</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://www.example.com">
</head>
<body>
<p>
Redirecting to our main site. If you're not redirected within a couple of seconds, click here:<br />
<a href="http://www.example.com">example.com</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Simple as that. Can find the same example [here](http://webmaster.iu.edu/tools-and-guides/maintenance/redirect-meta-refresh.phtml).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to [catherine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2008506/catherine) answer, updated to Python 3 is:

```
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

NEW_DOMAIN = 'www.newdomain.com'
```

Put in each `view`:

```
def myView(request, my_id):
    if request.META['HTTP_HOST'] != NEW_DOMAIN:
        # remove the args if not needed
        destination = reverse('url_tag', args=[my_id])
        full_address = urljoin(DOMAIN, str(destination))
        return HttpResponseRedirect(full_address)
    # your view here
```

The `url_tag` is the one defined in `urlpatterns`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended with simple solution:

```
return HttpResponse(f"<script>location.replace('https://example.com/');</script>")
```

It works if user don't disable scripts in webbrowser

Answer (score 0):

You could do it simply adding the redirect in the value 'urlpattens' found in 'urls.py'. Hope it helps. The reference is [source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/).

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect


urlpatterns = [
    path('old-path/', lambda request: redirect('new-path/', permanent=False)),
]
```