# Apache redirect empty subdomain to www-subdomain

Tags: apache, redirect

I am kinda new in apache config.

I wish to redirect my traffic from `http://example.com` to `http://www.example.com`

I want www always appear in my visitor's browser's address bar.

Should i use mod_rewrite or anything else in httpd.conf?

Comment: possible duplicate of [apache redirect from non www to www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343/apache-redirect-from-non-www-to-www)

Comment: Sorry, there are already tons of questions on this site about redirecting www to nothing or nothing to www using apache. Use the search-function for a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName adomainwihtoutwww.com
        Redirect permanent / http://www.yourdomain.com/
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: `Redirect permanent` is not recommended if you want to add subdomains later. A user who used that subdomain before it was registred as virtual host may never reach that page since there is `301 Moved Permanently` in its browser's cache.