# Dns add www prefix?

Tags: php, apache, dns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [apache redirect from non www to www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343/apache-redirect-from-non-www-to-www)

Is it possible to configure DNS to add www. prefix to the domain name?

[Here is an example of this](http://fiwe.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. You have to configure the webserver at `yourdomain.com` to redirect to `www.yourdomain.com`.

For example, on apache, you can use this configuration (using `mod_alias`):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.yourdomain.com
  ## Actual configuration here...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ## redirect non-www to www
  ServerName www.yourdomain.com
  ServerAlias yourdomain.com

  RedirectMatch permanent ^(.*) http://www.yourdomain.com$1
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You should add a NS A entry to the DNS record for both normalurl.com and www.normalurl.com
2. Enable mod_rewrite on Apache and create a .htaccess file with the following entries:

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.normalurl.com$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$      http://www.normalurl.com/$1 [L,R]
> ```

Comment: `.htaccess` is bad. Better to add some mod_alias stuff to the vhost configuration file, in order to be sure redirection always happens / avoid infinite redirect-loops, etc. Plus, that's way much easier to read configuration, if it's all in one place..

Comment: This is correct if you do have access to the vhost configuration; it might be an issue on many shared hosting environments, though.

Answer (score 0):

A DNS response contains a mapping of a domain name to an IP address. While you could alias example.net to www.example.net with a CNAME record, this would not be visible for the user.

Most likely, you want to [configure your web server to send an HTTP 301 redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343/apache-redirect-from-non-www-to-www) to the correct URL.