# How to redirect directory to sub-domain, and www sub-domain to non-www sub-domain?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, virtualhost

***NOTE:*** Using `<VirtualHost>` parameter only.

How do I redirect a directory (say `example.com/groups/`) to a sub-domain (say `groups.example.com`), and also the www of that sub-domain (`www.groups.example.com`) to the non-www URL of that sub-domain (`groups.example.com`)?

---

Precisely (⇒ stands for 'should 301 redirect to'):

`example.com/groups/` ⇒ `groups.example.com`

`www.groups.example.com` ⇒ `groups.example.com`

---

I have read that using `<VirtualHost>` is better than all those redirection rules that are usually used (i.e. that using redirection engine [is pretty heavy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1100363/1071413) on disk i/o). So, I would like to have the above problem solved using `<VirtualHost>` in .htaccess / httpd.conf if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com 
    ServerAlias groups.example.com www.groups.example.com

    RewriteEngine on
    # example.com/groups/ -> groups.example.com
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME}  ^example\.com$
    RewriteRule ^/(\w+)/?$  http://$1.example.com [R=301,L]

    # www.groups.example.com -> groups.example.com
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME}  ^www\.(\w+)\.example\.com$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://%1.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

or specifically for groups

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com 
    ServerAlias groups.example.com www.groups.example.com

    RewriteEngine on
    # example.com/groups/ -> groups.example.com
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME}  ^example\.com$
    RewriteRule ^/groups/?$  http://groups.example.com [R=301,L]

    # www.groups.example.com -> groups.example.com
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME}  ^www\.groups\.example\.com$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://groups.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It doesn't work because you are missing the directory (/groups/) in the second line. Can you please correct it? **EDIT:** Something's wrong. It doesn't work even after making that correction.

Comment: Tested both on my server, they work. Maybe you didn't add RewriteEngine on before those lines? Modified my answer to reflect a sample httpd configuration