# non-www to www .htaccess redirect not working?

Tags: .htaccess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [apache redirect from non www to www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343/apache-redirect-from-non-www-to-www)

I want my domain to redirect the non-www to the www version. For some reason the below code isn't working.

Any suggestions?

Most probably any easy fix, but I can't get it to work.

```
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
<filesmatch \.(css|html|js|php|xml)$>
    setoutputfilter deflate
</filesmatch>
</ifmodule>
<ifmodule mod_security.c>
secfilterengine off
secfilterscanpost off
</ifmodule>

<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^trailerpulse.com/
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.trailerpulse.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{request_filename} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$  index.php?a=$1&q=$3    [L]

</ifmodule>
<ifmodule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0
<filesmatch \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$>
    ExpiresDefault A604800
</filesmatch>
<filesmatch \.(html|xml)$>
    ExpiresDefault A10800
</filesmatch>
</ifmodule>

FileEtag None
Options All -Indexes
ServerSignature Off
ErrorDocument 404 /error
```

Comment: Why are you using mod_rewrite for that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343/apache-redirect-from-non-www-to-www/1100363#1100363

Comment: It's the way the code was written when I bought the script the site is based off.

Comment: Fair enough. I suggest moving to using the `Redirect` directive as mentioned in that linked question, it's much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule is almost there. The only problem is that you have a trailing slash after the hostname, which would *never* appear in the "Host:" header of the request. Replace the `/` with `$` and add `[NC]` flag to ignore case:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^trailerpulse.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.trailerpulse.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```