# Noob and Newbie for .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

obviously i need some advice for this one cause im new and theres nothing more better than an experienced and expert regarding these topic.

second you may know its always been a problem and many post have been given related to this topic but since i read alot, it said that "its powerful so be careful when editing the file" so it makes me nervous to make an advance for this one.

third i just want a code for every simple cases i have.

heres the cases:

example.com to www.example.com (i dont know if everything under these would be the same as www.example.com/files/files/files or it would show example.com/file/file/file)

PHP cases, specifics:

from a get method
example.com/product.php?prodtype=shirts&prodname=thecoolshirt
rewrite to
example.com/product/shirts/thecoolshirt (what if the name has spaces from string? how could i delete that in to this)

thanks in advance and sorry for being so selfish but i do really need some help

Answer (score 0):

First one you should find easily online, just by searching "rewrite non-www to www",
second one is easy, should be something like this ( might need simple editing, haven't done much apache rewrites since i moved to nginx, edits for fixing are welcome

```
RewriteRule /product/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /product.php?prodtype=$1&prodname=$2
```

**EDIT**: Use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343/apache-redirect-from-non-www-to-www) for your first question, guess I'll just paste you a link to see.

Comment: will the site.com/home.php will be www.site.com/home.php ???

and how would i turn site.com/home.php and any case like that into www.site.com/home/  ???

Comment: like i said search for the term i mentioned, you use something called rewrite condition.