# Redirect to www - htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I would like redirect site on start if address is without www.
For example if:

```
http://page.com - should redirect to http://www.page.com
http://page.com/news/first - should redirect http://www.page.com/news/first
```

i have:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
  RewriteRule . http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

why this not working? How can i make it?

Comment: Do you have the `mod_rewrite` module installed and enabled? Do you also have `RewriteEngine On` before the first `RewriteCond`?

Comment: yes, i have also others condition, but only this not working

Comment: If you have more to your `.htaccess` please post it. There could be something before these lines causing an issue.

Comment: Check out the "related" sidebar on this page. There are many examples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [apache redirect from non www to www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343/apache-redirect-from-non-www-to-www)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Make sure this is first rule just after `RewriteEngine On` line.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. Place these as the first lines in your `.htaccess`. If you already have the  `RewriteEngine on` statement just ignore it and use the last two lines.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.).+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```