# Redirecting user from root domain to www version of openshift app

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, openshift

I have osclass website at openshift free tier.but for openshift only www version of domain is working not root.My site htaccess file have follow content. what i add to .htaccess file so that it automatically redirect user from http;//mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [apache redirect from non www to www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343/apache-redirect-from-non-www-to-www)

Answer (score 1):

Add this rule just below `RewriteBase /` line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: is this right <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: anubhava i add mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com alias at openshift server is it is working.i am little bit scared while editing .htaccess file any suggestion for backup the osclass .htaccess file