# Remove www from the url

Tags: .htaccess, url, no-www

Does anyone have the setttings from the .htaccess file to remove www from my url?

http://example.com

I've tried using some of the settings in the internet but it gives me a redirect loop. I need something that prevents a redirect loop.

this would really help me. thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [apache redirect from non www to www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343/apache-redirect-from-non-www-to-www)

Comment: Hi, right now our goal does not involve Apache. Thanks for answer though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this code in your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you're still having a redirect loop:

- you have maybe another script that redirects non-www to www
- old rule still in browser's cache (try cleaning cache or with another browser)

Comment: Thanks Justin I'll test this setting and let you know if this works.