# Cross Domain error while using fonts

Tags: php, .htaccess, fonts, cross-domain

I have come across an error when trying to access my site with http://www.example.com instead of http://eample.com. My font icons will not load. So when searching for the solution to this I came across
the following solution which was adding the below code to a .htaccess file on the server.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(svg|ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://example.com, http://www.example.com"
</IfModule>
```

This managed to fix the problem but for Chrome only. How can i fix the issue for all browsers.

Thank you

Comment: How are you including your fonts? The fix could be as simple as using relative URL's not absolute, instead of messing around with your .htaccess file.

Comment: fonts are stored in a directory called fonts in the root. Then the css file i am using the href="http://example.com/css/font-awesome.min.css"

Comment: The issue would be resolved if you enforced the WWW cname. Might be a possible duplicate of [apache redirect from non www to www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343/apache-redirect-from-non-www-to-www)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
href="/css/font-awesome.min.css"
```

This will be relative to the domain they visitor is on, so if they connect to either `http://` or `http://www` the fonts will load and there won't be a cross domain error

Comment: Thanks Karl I fixed the issue thanks to your answer. The orginal reason I was not using /css/... was becasue I was storing my header content in a seperate header.php file and then including it in all other files. This meant that if a page was stored in a subfolder the /css/... path would break. Therefore I had to define a constant that took in the url entered into the browser and added that to all css and js links.