# Redirect www to naked domain

Tags: apache, redirect, ssl, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to redirect all of my website traffic to my naked domain (looks much cleaner in my opinion), but when Googling I found a LOT of different methods for going about it. I use CloudFlare's free SSL, so I'd like a solution that works both with and without SSL (in case something happens and I disable the SSL or whatever), and I'd preferably like to do this globally (i.e. without a .htaccess file). In case it matters, this is Apache 2.4.10 on Ubuntu Server 14.10.

I found [this article](http://www.dragonbe.com/2013/11/apache-rewrite-rules-from-your-naked.html), but placing his code (below) into my VirtualHost directive gave the error that is below. The Apache error log doesn't have anything useful. What can I do to fix this problem and make it so the redirect works properly? (If I should be doing this some other way I'm open to that as well; I have access to control my DNS settings and whatnot if needed.)

Code inserted into `apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Error code I receive when restarting Apache:

```
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 30 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:
Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Comment: Would this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343/apache-redirect-from-non-www-to-www

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rewrite` module is not enabled by default.

1. Enable the rewrite module:

   sudo a2enmod rewrite
2. change your `000-default.conf` to

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
   ```
3. then

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

Comment: Oh jeez, I didn't think to check if `mod_rewrite` was enabled! Always the simple things. Your code now works to remove the `www` from the beginning of the URL, but it adds two `/`s to the end: both `https://domain.com` and `https://www.domain.com` redirect to `https://domain.com//`. I would like for it to not add a trailing slash at all (unless there's a reason a trailing slash *should* be added, in which case I'm fine with it). I tried figuring out the regex involved but I'm lost.