# Force non-www to www

Tags: apache, redirect, ubuntu-14.04

I have the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/webmaster/example.com/web

        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com

        <Directory /var/www/webmaster/example.com/web>
                Options  +ExecCGI
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

         RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]  
         RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com$1 [last,redirect=301]

</VirtualHost>
```

However when I view http://example.com it stays at http://example and does not go to http://www.example.com

This is even after trying all the other mentioned posts such as: [apache redirect from non www to www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343/apache-redirect-from-non-www-to-www)

Comment: you're basically saying `if http_host = example.com, redierct`. You need `if http_host IS NOT example.com`, e.g. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$`

Comment: @MarcB Sorry I did have that (failed copy n paste). I tried your "~^example.com" (I thought it would be "! instead of a ~" but that also didn't work.

Comment: yeah, `~` was a typo from trying to type up the comment and talking on the phone. for my next trick: chewing gum and blinking at the same time.