# Laravel 5 "www" and naked domain routing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I would like to ask what approach should i use to handle naked domain routing in laravel 5? Given scenario like this, when a user types in example.com, I can use

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'example.com'], function(){
    Route::get('/', function() {
        return Redirect::to(URL::route('/'));
    });
});
```

noted that `route('/')` has been namespaced in the route groups **www.example.com**

so my question is, what if a user enters **example.com/something/very/interesting**, how should I redirect the user back to **www.example.com/something/very/interesting** ? Bare in mind that I would also like to do this to all other actions. Which means at any point of time when a user enters `example.com/*` it will bring the user back to `www.example.com/*`

Thank You

Comment: You should used [.htaccess](http://www.htaccessbasics.com/force-www-nonwww-domain/) to force user use only www or non-www domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more effectively solved by your web server rather than at the Laravel level of things. If you are using Apache check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1100363/425519). If you are using Nginx then check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7958540/425519).

You are wanting to force the user to www.example.com so you will need to update your route group to the following;

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'www.example.com'], function () {
    // The rest of your routes
});
```