# Add WWW to URL when it's not present on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, rails-routing

I want to force my URL to start with `www.` when it's not present.

I tried the `match` method, but it seems to ignore the start of the URL, it seems to do something called Route Globbing, that appearently just works with route segments http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments

How do I make my application in RoR always start with www. ?
-> www.foo.com must remain as it is
-> foo.com must be redirected to www.foo.com

Answer (score 3):

It's better to do it in nginx or apache (depends on what you're using). Please see these topics:

**For nginx**
[Nginx no-www to www and www to no-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947030/nginx-no-www-to-www-and-www-to-no-www)

**For Apache**
[apache redirect from non www to www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343/apache-redirect-from-non-www-to-www)

Comment: Why is it better to do it in nginx or apache?

Comment: Because further you may face a problem of redirecting from http to https for example. Because nginx is written using C with focusing on such tasks, so it will be faster than Rails.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider a rack middleware like [rack-www](https://github.com/stjhimy/rack-www) or [rack-rewrite](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite). Setup of `rack-www` is only two steps:

```
# Add to Gemfile (and run `bundler`)
gem 'rack-www'

# configure middleware via `application.rb` (for all environments)
# or the environment specific configuration file
# `environments/<environment>.rb`
config.middleware.use Rack::WWW, :www => true
```