# Canonical URL’s for Magento

Tags: .htaccess, magento

Canonical URL's for Magento: Currently website has multiple url for one page.

Need to redirect below given url using 301 redirection, example:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php/
http://www.example.com/
http://example.com/index.php/
http://example.com/
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/
```

Need it for SEO purpose, Otherwise Search Engine is treating each page as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the steps

- http://www.example.com/ in system->configuration->General -> Web -> unsecure and secure
- Enable search Engine optimization in **System -> Configuration -> Web -> Search Engines Optimizations**, select **YES**

Now, add below code in .htaccess file **to remove index.php** from url

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Now add below code in .htaccess file to always redirect to http://www

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can follow following steps

- Enable apache **mode_rewrite**
- http://www.example.com/ in system->configuration->General -> Web -> unsecure and secure
- Enable search Engine optimization in **System -> Configuration -> Web -> Search Engines Optimizations**, select **YES**
- check if `RewriteBase /` in .htaccess. if DOCUMENT_ROOT is another directory than `RewriteBase /MAGENTO_DIR/`

Alternatively, you can also redirect to virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

This [apache redirect from non www to www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343/apache-redirect-from-non-www-to-www) might be helpful for you

Comment: If you did not change anything index.php Above step 1, 2 and 3 will work without any problem. 
redirect where? I don't think you have to change anything in VirtualHost

Comment: If i enter http://www.example.com/index.php/category.html  then it should redirect to http://www.example.com/category.html