# how to auto change my site url from http:// to http://www. in browser address bar

Tags: php, session, url

In my `constants.php` file, I have set site root.

```
 define("SITEROOT","http://www.example.com/");
```

please see for difference in http:// and http://www. in following description.

Now session_start works only if I move from **http://www.example.com/index.php** to any other page. But if I use **http://example.com** and tried to echo session details on other page with **http://www.example.com/pagename.php**, session is not continued.

Is there any way to auto correct url in *browser's address bar* to **http://www.example.com** if user uses **http://example.com** ?

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your web server to force either www or non-www urls. It is highly recommended to use one of them (not allowing both) on live websites for search indexing perposes.

If you're using Apache you can do so by updating your site `.htaccess` file as follows for url's without www

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

**Update**

As Vinny has pointed out in the comments it is recommended when ever possible to **NOT** use .htaccess and instead handle it in the [Virtual Host Config file](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/vhosts/examples.html).

Comment: @darshan Glad i could help, please remember that you not allow the website to be accessed with www and non-www when you get your website live :)

Comment: I didn't get your point in comment...Do u mean, only myexample.com with http and www in first position will work - open in browser and not only http in myexample.com ? because i tried ur code in htaccess and site without www prefixed is auto corrected with www prefixed in browser...which i want..

Comment: @darshan I mean (for example) if your domain is mydomain.org don't allow the website to be visited via www.mydomain.org (with www) & mydomain.org (non-www) search engines such as google see this as duplicate contents and this effects your search ranking :)

Comment: This answer although correct is bad form for a production server, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343/apache-redirect-from-non-www-to-www

Comment: @VinnyMannello I agree with you here, VirtualHost must be used where ever possible but in most shared hostings sometimes .htaccess is the only option. I will update my answer to include that, Thank you for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using apache add this to your config.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: ohhh..very good alternative... I will try this also and will let you know...thank you for suggestion..

Comment: Rewrites are intense and messy:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343/apache-redirect-from-non-www-to-www

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use something like this (before anything is displayed, or headers sent, so before your session creation code):

```
if( "www." != substr( $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"], 0, 4 ) ){
    header( "Location: http://www.example.com".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] );
    exit();
}
```

Alternately, you could create/modify your .htaccess file like this:

```
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.domain.com
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301]
```

or maybe

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. It is perfect..But Ahren answered 6 minutes before you and I tried that solution first and it worked for me..so marking his answer as right / accepted answer.Sorry n Thank you once again