# Ruby on Rails www subdomain redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Here is my Ruby on Rails code to redirect a request from `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
before_filter :add_www_subdomain

private

    def add_www_subdomain
      if Rails.env.production?
        unless /^www/.match(request.host)
          redirect_to("#{request.protocol}www.#{request.host_with_port}",status: 301)
        end
      end
    end
end
```

Now the issue is, when someone lands at `https://example.com/product/abc` they are being redirected to `https://www.example.com` supposedly, they should go to  `https://www.example.com/product/abc`. Is there any trick for this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
redirect_to("#{request.protocol}www.#{request.host_with_port}#{request.fullpath}",status: 301)
```

I think this kind of redirect is more suited to the web server. These are the rules:

**Apache**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343/apache-redirect-from-non-www-to-www)

**NGINX**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    # $scheme will get the http protocol
    # and 301 is best practice for tablet, phone, desktop and seo
    return 301 $scheme://domain.com$request_uri;
```

}

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    # here goes the rest of your config file
    # example 
    location / {

        rewrite ^/cp/login?$ /cp/login.php last;
        # etc etc...

    }
}
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947030/nginx-no-www-to-www-and-www-to-no-www)