# how to use single site for www and root in django sites framework

Tags: python, django, .htaccess, subdomain, django-sites

I currently have a single site, but I want to expand to several sites for use in django.

I currently must have two entries in my django_sites table for my single site:

```
1   mysite.com  My Site
2   www.mysite.com  My Site
```

Now that I want to have multiple sites, having multiple entries per subdomain is not feasible anymore since I want to create many to many relationships with objects associated with the sites.

**How can I use a single www and root domain per site instead of the two?**

Answer (score 0):

I handled this at the apache level in the httpd and ssl.conf

I followed this answer here [apache redirect from non www to www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343/apache-redirect-from-non-www-to-www)