# is this possible with php protocol base url

Tags: php, html, redirect

So - I have made a website with php includes in my header I have the following

```
<?php
$protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? 'https' : 'http';
$path = $protocol . '://domain.com/';
?>
```

but for some reason when I put www. in the URL bar, it breaks the site
I even have a 301 direct in cpanel

is there a way to add www or no www to this?

Comment: Rewriting to include httpS and/or www is usually easiest by using `.htaccess` and letting the web server handle rewriting things.

Comment: this is how the site was developed from whomever i have been working with it, and within the the site all images etc are being called to the $path, it would take too long to change everything

Comment: If `$path` is used to load images and resources from your own site, why aren't you using a relative path? Can't you just set `$path` to `/`?

Comment: See my answer....

Comment: www. is part of the host

Comment: It is a good practice to have one canonical host (e.g. I prefer non-www since it’s just shorter) and redirect other variants to the canonical one (e.g. from www to non-www).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to have a function for absolute `http(s)` path, the best way is check if server responses as `HTTP` or `HTTPS` and rewrite the php code according to new path...

`check.php`

```
<?php
  // Checking for HTTP or HTTPS
  function check_protocol() {
    $isSecure = false;
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) == 'on') {
      $isSecure = true;
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) == 'https' || !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL']) == 'on') {
      $isSecure = true;
    }
    return $isSecure;
  }
  $protocol = check_protocol() ? 'https://' : 'http://';
  $host = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
?>
```

Usage is simple:

```
<?php
  include("check.php");
  echo $host;
  // it prints http://www.example.com or https://www.example.com
?>
```

or using the absolute path thanks to [$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

```
<?php
  include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/php/check.php");
  echo $host;
  // it prints http://www.example.com or https://www.example.com
?>
```

In addition to this may be useful a redirect using `.htaccess` if the server is hosted on `Apache` server...

I found useful this rule for my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

This rule may not work on different server configuration... read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite) thread for getting more info about the most different sever configuration...

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeh the above code doesn't work when they put www. after the http://www. breaks anything that relies on $host , i can't figure it out,

even in cpanl we added the redirect with either www or not www

Comment: Investigate on your VirtualHost

Comment: All servers can handle www or not without problems, see ServerName and ServerAlias into your VirtualHost... read [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/155658/apache-virtual-host-config-www-vs-non-www-rewrite-or-sserveralias) or [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/191218/apache-isnt-respecting-the-servername-directive-for-a-particular-site) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343/apache-redirect-from-non-www-to-www)

Comment: when i add this 
<img src="<?php echo $host; ?>images/logo.jpg" alt=""/>
for a example .. it loads nothing... your example does work though with i use the check.php

Comment: Happy to hear that...Glad to help!

Comment: the issue - i was trying it on xampp first and it was in a sub folder so it was only loading http://localhost and not the sub folder not sure why, but on the live site it works. do you think i have to do something different for local server setup with folders? I'll probably have to change the $host to the actually URL i think

Comment: if you replicate the structure of the server you have online I think not

Comment: some adaptations should be made only if you really have a different folder structure than your local server

Comment: http.//localhost/ is to be considered an absolute path, do not confuse it with `$_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` which is another thing and does not concern the loading of the contents http ...

Comment: If you write http://localhost/images/logo.png wherever you are you will be able to see the image as long as the url is correctly written...

Comment: With `<img src="<?php echo $host; ?>/images/logo.jpg" alt="Image">` you should see the image correctly...

Comment: If you have problems including `check.php` from another folder you can use `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/php/check.php");` this an absolute path for including php files...