# Redirecting www to non www in dns records

Tags: security, redirect, dns, certificate

We have printed a ton of business cards with a QR code point to https://www.example.com/ . Problem is that there is no security certificates on the www sub domain so every time you scan the qr code it says "This connection is not private". https://example.com/ does have a security certificate.

Now, instead of me throwing all these business cards away, what can I change/add to the DNS records so that the QR code https://www.example.com/ redirects to https://example.com/

Thanks

Comment: You can't.  Get a certificate for the domain.

Answer (score -1):

Its a simple change to be done on your web server. For example, if you are using apache, there is small configuration which can redirect non-www to www.

So, for users opening your website by: https://example.com, they will get a redirect to https://www.example.com

Thats simple, and do not require a new certificate.

For reference on how to do it, see: [apache redirect from non www to www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343/apache-redirect-from-non-www-to-www)