# How do I redirect all non-www traffic to www in digitalocean

Tags: .htaccess, digital-ocean

I'm trying to redirect all https://example.com to https://www.example.com and I can't find anything that works. I want to do this as I think it will look better and it will make logging in easier as you currently have to login at both domains as they're treated as being different.
I added this .htaccess file in case this is what I've got wrong?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apache redirect from non www to www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343/apache-redirect-from-non-www-to-www)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
# Redirect to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Is there a way to test this withou having to update my production code?

Comment: I've tried this and it didn't work unfortunately

Comment: did you replaced the example.com with your domain ?

Comment: @willmahoney please check the edits, I added a more generic solution.

Comment: it didn't work, I think I have to update it in the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file, as this seems to be overruling the .htaccess file

Comment: `I think I have to update it in the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file` - if you aren't using apache, editing `.htaccess` files will have no effect.

Comment: Does this mean I can delete my .htaccess file from my react public folder then?