# Why aren't .htaccess rewrite conditions to secure non-WWW URLs are not working on mobile browsers?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem with a site that I'm working on. There are a few sites located in the same environment. The server uses one SSL certificate that protects these domains like such: domain1.com, [www.domain1.com](http://www.domain1.com) and [www.domain2.com](http://www.domain2.com).

The SSL certificate does not protect domain2.com without the www subdomain.

The problem is that (specifically on mobile) domain2.com is not being protected. If we visit [www.domain2.com](http://www.domain2.com), it is protected.

Why are the following conditions not working on mobile to redirect the site to the www version before the warning is thrown that the site is not secure?

```
# Redirect Non-WWW to WWW
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.\*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Force SSL on entire site
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.\*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
```

These are the first rules in the .htaccess file before WordPress is loaded.

Comment: Maybe answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343/apache-redirect-from-non-www-to-www

Comment: @OnkiHara, Unfortunately, this is some type of shared hosting environment and I don't have access to the Apache server config. Otherwise I would've done that.

Comment: If you don't have the cert you can't resolve the request. The browser attempts the handshake then the mapping. Since the handshake cant occur you get the notice. Sounds like `domain2.com` is not a wildcard cert but domain1 has wildcard cert

Comment: `SSL certificate that protects` what does “protects” mean here?

Comment: Here’s one solution, tha does not involve your shared host handling that at all https://community.cloudflare.com/t/redirecting-one-domain-to-another/81960

Comment: "specifically on mobile" - It should be _all_ modern browsers, both desktop _and_ mobile. Unless, you have at some point "accepted" an invalid cert on the desktop browser?

Answer (score 1):

Based on browser security settings including non-mobile, the warning is shown before http request is sent, to prevent exposing information over non-secure connection, that is the reason why modrewrite won't solve this, simply because it's not even invoked. You should include your "domain2.com" as alternative name in your SSL certificate.