# Weird Wordpress Error - Server Issues/ htaccess/ functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

Anyone know why this URL works flawlessly:
http://plumcreekgarlic.com/

But this URL leads to a Wordpress error?
http://www.plumcreekgarlic.com/

Is this is a Wordpress issue or a server/ a-record/ htaccess issue?

Thanks!

myHTAccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

My functions.php file (part of a thematic child theme I built):

```
/* ADD CUSTOM JQUERY */

function childtheme_scripts() {?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://plumcreekgarlic.com/wp-content/themes/plumcreek/custom_jquery.js"></script>
<?php }
add_action('wp_head','childtheme_scripts');
?>

<?php
/* ADJUST CATEGORY TITLES 
Info here: http://www.cozmoslabs.com/forums/topic/change-title-for-category-archive
*/
function street_page_title() {
        $content = '';
        if (is_attachment()) {
                $content .= '<h2 class="page-title"><a href="';
                $content .= get_permalink($post->post_parent);
                $content .= '" rev="attachment"><span class="meta-nav">&laquo; </span>';
                $content .= get_the_title($post->post_parent);
                $content .= '</a></h2>';
        } elseif (is_author()) {
                $content .= '<h1 class="page-title author">';
                $author = get_the_author();
                $content .= __('Author Archives: ', 'thematic');
                $content .= '<span>';
                $content .= $author;
                $content .= '</span></h1>';
        } elseif (is_category()) {
                $content .= '<h1 class="entry-title">';
                $content .= __('', 'thematic');
                $content .= ' <span>';
                $content .= single_cat_title('', FALSE);
                $content .= '</span></h1>' . "\n";
                $content .= '<div class="archive-meta">';
                if ( !(''== category_description()) ) : $content .= apply_filters('archive_meta', category_description()); endif;
                $content .= '</div>';
        } elseif (is_search()) {
                $content .= '<h1 class="page-title">';
                $content .= __('Search Results for:', 'thematic');
                $content .= ' <span id="search-terms">';
                $content .= wp_specialchars(stripslashes($_GET['s']), true);
                $content .= '</span></h1>';
        } elseif (is_tag()) {
                $content .= '<h1 class="page-title">';
                $content .= __('Tag Archives:', 'thematic');
                $content .= ' <span>';
                $content .= __(thematic_tag_query());
                $content .= '</span></h1>';
        }   elseif (is_day()) {
                $content .= '<h1 class="page-title">';
                $content .= sprintf(__('Daily Archives: <span>%s</span>', 'thematic'), get_the_time(get_option('date_format')));
                $content .= '</h1>';
        } elseif (is_month()) {
                $content .= '<h1 class="page-title">';
                $content .= sprintf(__('Monthly Archives: <span>%s</span>', 'thematic'), get_the_time('F Y'));
                $content .= '</h1>';
        } elseif (is_year()) {
                $content .= '<h1 class="page-title">';
                $content .= sprintf(__('Yearly Archives: <span>%s</span>', 'thematic'), get_the_time('Y'));
                $content .= '</h1>';
        } elseif (isset($_GET['paged']) && !empty($_GET['paged'])) {
                $content .= '<h1 class="page-title">';
                $content .= __('Blog Archives', 'thematic');
                $content .= '</h1>';
        }
        $content .= "\n";
return $content;

}
add_filter('thematic_page_title', 'street_page_title');
?>
```

Comment: What kind of a Wordpress error?

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/16/7272716/html/wp-content/themes/plumcreek/functions.php:63) in /home/content/16/7272716/html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 890

Comment: The thing I really don't understand is what the www has to do with the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this thread http://wordpress.org/support/topic/cannot-modify-header-information-pluggablephp-on-line-865?replies=9

It says to check the functions.php if there are spaces before the starting `<?php` tag and after the `?>` closing tag.

Quoting [Shane G](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/cannot-modify-header-information-pluggablephp-on-line-865?replies=9#post-1329998):

> 1. Download the file mentioned in the error message.
> 2. Open that file in a plain text editor
> 3. Check that the very first characters are
>
>    Check that the very last characters are ?>
>
>    Place the cursor between the ? and >
>
>    Now press the DELETE key on your computer and keep that key pressed for
>      at least 15 seconds.
>
>    Now type > and
>
>    Save without pressing any other key at all.

If this fixes it then it's a WordPress problem. You might have a plugin that redirects users using www.plumcreekgarlic.com to plumcreekgarlic.com, but then as error says, header information (location) cannot be sent when output is started already.

If you have such a plugin, the delete this and use [htaccess to redirect users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www/1270281#1270281):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```