# $_SESSION working only in website.com, not in www.website.com

Tags: php, session

If I login through website.com and then type www.website.com, it doesn't show that I am login in and I have to do that again. What's the problem?

Comment: Problem is that website.com and www.website.com are not the same domains, therefore you need to set your session_id cookie to be allowed at www.website.com too.

Comment: Check the session cookie established when you visit `website.com`. If there's no leading `.`, then it applies ONLY to website.com and not any 'sub' version, such as the `www.` one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal. Session cookies apply to the exact domain they were issued by default. `www.website.com` is a different domain from `website.com`.

You can expand the scope of the cookie to sub-domains, but the much better way is to actually have only either `www.website.com` or `website.com`, and to redirect one to the other.

For  redirecting `www` to non-www, see

- [Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)

Comment: Thanks, and how can I do that?

Comment: This answer would be even better if you demonstrated.

Comment: @hey which way do you want it? I edited a good answer for one way into the question

Answer (score 3):

This should fix it:

```
session_set_cookie_params(
  60 * 24,        // 24 minutes lifetime
  '/',            // path
  '.website.com', // any subdomain of website.com
  false,          // SSL not required
  true            // not accessible by JavaScript
);

session_start();
```

Comment: This answer would be even better if you explained it.

Comment: @Tomalak, I don't disagree. But I'm lazy and two people already had responded with a "why" as comments to the original question. :)