# Non www to www using httpd.conf - // error

Tags: apache, redirect

When I use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

in my httpd.conf file, why is my site redirecting to www.example.com//
(www.example.com//file.html). Why are there two slashes ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

EDIT:

The above `RewriteCond` was probably overkill - it was intended to only match urls that are not preceded by `www`.  However this should work too:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Like David Chan mentioned, the `^(.*)$` is what you were missing.  The `^` and `$` are special characters in Regular Expressions.  Here is a link that explains regex string anchors: http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Also, here is a link that can explain the mod_rewrite syntax in more detail: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: ^(.*)$ is the key difference.