# Redirect www. to bare domain when using SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, mod-ssl

**Some context**: I'm serving a website under the domains `domain.com` and `alternate-domain.com`. I would like to redirect all requests so that they:

1. use SSL (basically, redirect http -> https)
2. use the canonical hostname `domain.com` (e.g. remove the `www` prefix)

That's what I have at the top of my apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  Redirect permanent / https://domain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:433>
  Redirect permanent / https://domain.com/
  SSLEngine on

  # SSL Certificate directives are here.
</VirtualHost>
```

And then later on I have the config for https://domain.com:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName domain.com
  # ...
</VirtualHost>
```

This works as expected when I access non-HTTPS pages:

- http://www.domain.com redirects to `https://domain.com`
- http://alternate-domain.com redirects to `https://domain.com`

However, **it doesn't work when I access domains through HTTPS**. What I mean by that is that *the redirection doesn't happen*.

Examples:

- https://www.domain.com
- https://alternate-domain.com

(Note: it's normal that certificate warnings occur as they don't match the domain for which I have the certificate. All the more reason for redirecting users.)

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Also, I'd like to avoid `mod_rewrite`. Related but didn't help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, problem solved - I made a typical stupid mistake.

In the SSL default vhost, I listen on port `433`. Should be `443`of course.

Comment: Note that the certificate you're using will need to be valid for all the host names you're using (with and without `www`).

Comment: except that what are the chances a user would enter `https://www.domain.com` ? they'll probably enter `http://www.domain.com` which will then redirect to https

Answer (score 0):

Your config says that when someone enters a URL of https://groupstreamer.com/, the server should redirct them to https://groupstreamer.com/ - and you can't see the flaw here?

Lose the redirect in the 443 virtualhost. If you must use a front controller (which is wrong for so many reasons) then use the 404 handler.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not how virtualhosts work - Apache matches the ServerName directive and uses the first virtualhost for domains that didn't match.