# .htaccess error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

htaccess in one of my site but getting funny error when i try to open site with http://www.online4movies.com/ it dont work, if i don't use http://online4movies.com/ it work

here is the code

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.online4movies.com
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.online4movies.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{request_filename} -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$  index.php?a=$1&q=$3    [L]

</ifmodule>
```

Comment: "if i don't use http://online4movies.com/ it work" Huh? What is that? Empty address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with the above rules, but the one that is really causing you a problem is that you forgot a `!` in front of the right operand of the first `RewriteCond`.

Other things that are wrong include:

- dots `.` must be escaped to have their literal meaning in a regular expression, which is what the second argument to `RewriteCond` is.
- the `(.*)` would be much safer if you included `^$`
- `request_filename` should be capitalised
- Rewriting a URL to itself is confusing and unnecessary, simply pass `-` as the second argument to the `RewriteRule` instead. But there is no need for that rule, simply negate the `RewriteCond` and apply it to the next rule.

Try this file instead:

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Turn mod_rewrite on
    RewriteEngine on

    # Force a www on the beginning of the URL
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.online4movies\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.online4movies.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Parse URLs for files that don't exist and send them through index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$  index.php?a=$1&q=$3 [L]

</ifmodule>
```

Comment: thanks guys i figer out the error it was RewriteRule (.*) http://www.online4movies.com/$1 [R=301,L] , it should be RewriteRule (.*) http://online4movies.com/$1 [R=301,L] with no www any way thanks .

Answer (score 0):

I found some something related to same issue..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^my-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

"or"

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

link :- [Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)

Comment: thanks guys i figer out the error it was RewriteRule (.*) http://www.online4movies.com/$1 [R=301,L] , it should be RewriteRule (.*) http://online4movies.com/$1 [R=301,L] with no www any way thanks .