# Redirect ASPX to HTML

Tags: asp.net, html, redirect

My company recently switched hosts for their website, and as a result had get rid of .aspx pages and switch to .html. All was well and good until we found that a flash object has an embedded link to an old .aspx page. We can not edit the flash file without losing it due to corruption. It was made for us by an outside company.

Our only option at this point is to redirect from the old.aspx url to the new.html url. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Does your server still support aspx pages?

Comment: No it does not support aspx anymore which is where it gets tricky

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your htaccess file you can redirect it there.

[Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Apache web server now, this can save you a couple of hours

http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4445316.htm

Good luck!