# Redirect www to non-www is redirecting to script instead of nice URL

Tags: mod-rewrite

My domain **domain.com is redirected to www.domain.com** but, due to internal redirects, it only works in some cases:

- ***domain.com/folder/*** should redirect **to www.domain.com/folder/** but it is redirected to ***www.domain.com/blog/index.php***

The issue here is that internally, ***www.domain.com/folder/*** uses that **blog/index.php** throught a RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^$          ../blog/index.php
```

I don't know why, but you are redirected to the script instead of the nice URL.

IT WORKS here (redirection from **domain.com/folder/** to **www.domain.com/folder**, when all code within same "Directory" entry):

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/>
    Options -All +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    # redirect non-www to www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^domain\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$          http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

    RewriteRule ^folder/$           ../blog/index.php                       
</Directory>
```

It does NOT WORK here (redirection from **domain.com/folder/** to **www.domain.com/blog/index.php**, when 2 "Directory" entries are used):

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/>
    Options -All +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    # redirect non-www to www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^domain\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$          http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]                      
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/sonidon.com/httpdocs/folder/>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$          ../blog/index.php
</Directory>
```

Tested also using **Options +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch** in both directories with no luck :(

I saw a solution here using VirtualHosts instead of Directory:
[Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)
but think that it should be a way to do this because this trouble is not only related to "non-www to www" but to any redirection.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/>
    Options -All +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    # redirect non-www to www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^domain\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$          http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]                      
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/sonidon.com/httpdocs/folder/>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$          ../blog/index.php
    #ADDED LINE BELOW
    RewriteRule ^/$          ../blog/index.php
</Directory>
```

Try the line I added above. I think the issue is that "http://domain.com" was getting redirected to "http://www.domain.com/" (note the trailing slash). Then you were redirecting in the second group if there was no uri ^$, but in fact the uri was "/".

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that doesn't solve the issue. I have tried that line both above and above the another rewrite but it has no effect. I have also tried with different destination scripts for each of those 2 RedirectRules, and "RedirectRule ^$" is the one executed.

The most surprising of this issue is that I have been seeking deeper in StackOverflow and Google, and haven't found anyone with the same trouble.

Thanks a lot for your effort!