# Get subdomain from url?

Tags: php

I need to get some value from the url..
Like if the url was `http://www.random.mysite.com/`

Then I somehow want to get `random`.

But this should work aswell if it use `www`, `http://` or `https://` in-front of the url..

So how can this be done?

I tried this:
`array_shift(explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));`

It works if the url is `http://random.mysite.com/`, but if I put `www` in-front, then I get `www` returned instead?

Any ideas?

Comment: Check if you've got `www` and if so, just repeat the process again with the rest of the exploded parts? Or you could use a [regular expression](http://bg2.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
$url = 'http://random.mysite.com/';
$url = parse_url($url,PHP_URL_HOST);
$url = strstr(str_replace("www.","",$url), ".",true);
var_dump($url);
```

Answer (score 3):

URLs without http[s]:// in front are not URLs. They're strings.

```
$hostname = preg_replace('~^https?://(www\\.)?~i', null, $url); // shift scheme and www
$hostname = preg_replace('~#.*$~', null, $hostname); // pop target
$hostname = preg_replace('~\\?.*$~', null, $hostname); // pop query string
$hostname = preg_replace('~/.*$~', null, $hostname); // pop uri
// no guarantee it's a valid hostname, there's more checks you can do here
```

**Try this one.** Why three steps? To be explicit so you understand what it does and to cater for complicated cases when you have no / and a ? directly. The order is important too. It could be combined in one strike but you need some testing to do it right... There's so many malformed URLs out there when you scrape a bit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get everything after the `http://` and `https://` first.

Then, use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split the domain in different elements. For the special case where it could start with `www`, check the value of the first item in the exploded array. If the first one is `www`, then the second one must be the subdomain.

```
$url = 'http://www.sub.yourwebsite.com';
$parsed = parse_url($url);
$domain = explode('.', $parsed['host']);
$subdomain = '';

if ($domain[0] == 'www')
    $subdomain = $domain[1];
else
    $subdomain = $domain[0];
```

Comment: This doesn't work for non-http URLs. OP needs to parse URLs without a scheme as well.

Comment: It works fine with `https://`, `https://www.`, `http://`, and `http://www.`. OP, can you let us know if the specified URL is of any other case?

Comment: I'm not sure what OP needs either. But if the user entered "www.stacoverflow.com" (no http:// here), I think OP wants to get "www" from it. problem is that, parse_url doesn't work with such URLs.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you need it for, a cleaner solution might be to make sure you serve consistent URL's first. To redirect all http://yoursite.com to http://www.yoursite.com put this in your .htaccess file (in root directory assuming your using apache).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^your-site.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.your-site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

More variations of this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www). This also helps a little with SEO, and is generally good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of selecting the first part of the domain and check if it is www, you can also start from the back. After you exploded the domain name, the last part will be 'com' and the part before that is 'yoursite'. The part before that is either 'random' or 'www'. 'www' is a subdomain itself and you could even say that 'www.random' is a different subdomain from 'random'.

Disadvantage is that a TLD can be '.com', but it can be '.co.uk' as well, in which case 'yoursite' would be considered a subdomain, while it isn't really.

What you often see, especially in frameworks or libraries that can be used in multiple sites, is a setting that lets you specify the main host name (yoursite.com). That way, you can easily concluse that everything between `protocol://` and that host name is your subdomain.

Comment: can you tell me any library which will extract hostname from url?