# how to redirect http://www.mydomain.com/test/ to http://mydomain.com/test/

Tags: .htaccess

This code did not work for me:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I have tested a lot of things including [Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www), but it did not solved my problem.

Can any body help me to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^my-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```