# How to force htaccess to without www url

Tags: .htaccess, url

My htaccess right now:

```
# Use PHP 5.3
AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php


RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

I need to do a rule, that if somebody type `http://www.mypage.com/blog/blablatitle`

it redirects him to `http://mypage.com/blog/blablatitle`

and the same for the frontpage and all pages.

I am using CodeIgniter, but I think this is not so important when dealing with htaccess.

This suggested solution is not working well in CodeIgniter:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Because it adds index.php in the address e.g.: when I type:

```
http://www.mypage.com/blog/blablatitle
```

it redirects me to:

```
http://mypage.com/index.php?/blog/blablatitle
```

And I need:

```
http://mypage.com/blog/blablatitle
```

Without this rule it is ok (without index,php) e.g.: `http://mypage.com/blog/blablatitle`

So, any advice how to improve this redirect rule som index.php doesn't appear in the redirected link?

Comment: Believe your question is covered here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www

Comment: Thanks. I will try it. It is important to put it on the very first place (to the top above all)? Or it doesn's matter?

Comment: Ups, your link solution is not working. It adds index.php in the link when redirect in effect ;(

Comment: It has to be done slightly different for codeigniter I guess :(

Comment: SOLVED! ;) You need to put it right after RewriteEngine On  RewriteBase /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED! ;) You need to put it right after

```
RewriteBase /
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this please:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]`

`RewriteRule ^index.php(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]`