# .htaccess redirect from www and non www to https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I need a simple way to force an `https` redirect for incoming non-`https` requests.

In other words, if a request comes in for `http://www.example.com` or `http://example.com` I want it to be redirected to `https://www.example.com` or `https://example.com`, respectively.

Either of the two options is valid in my scenario - as long as both `www` and non-`www` requests get redirected.

I've tried a number of solutions based on a variety of resources, but most of them wind up with me getting an infinite loop - or some kind of error message that redirection has not been properly set-up.

I am using media temple as my host and would **love** to be able to do this via editing my `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Check out this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www it has lot of generic solutions for reference.

Comment: You should also consider canonicalising the www vs non-www.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```