# domain missing DNS CNAME for www

Tags: web, dns, cname

I am having an issue with a site which doesn't open with www but it works without www.

www and non-www site show different IP address. 
I know DNS CNAME is missing for wwww. 
But the case is i am working for a client which is out of contact for few days. So, I couldn't get the domain login details to modify CNAME. 
I tried writing redirection rule in .htacess but it doesn't show any effect.

Is there any other way to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules you need are (in the root of the www domain). The root of the non-www domain doesn't need an .htaccess for this to work (but may later).

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

find out more: [Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)

Once your client is back, hurry up, point www and non-www to the same hosting space, and decide which is prominent, google will not like if you have both www and non-www listed. Just the above rules or viceversa will do.
Also keep in mind that by changing domains or breaking routing you could lose ranking.