# How can I make it jump to the URL without www when it contains it?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to make `.htaccess`
On this, I would like to state something in order to make visitor jump to the URL without www when it contains it as sub-domain.

How can I write?
For example, when a user goes to the page http://www.test-sample.com/sign_up, I want it to redirect to http://test-sample.com/sign_up
but only when it contains www in sub-domain.
Because there is rare case such as http://forum.test-sample.com/1443

Comment: This looks to be a duplicate of:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www

Comment: @Nick Thanks I've already tried that but it takes me to `http://test-sample.com/test-sample/public` :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This will **only redirect `www.example.com` while leaving `www.sub.example.com` as it is**.

Comment: Thanks!! you are right!! It was because of cache! Thanks so much:)

Comment: MKK: The code provided in this answer should work fine. Make this as simple as you can, and just create an index.html file (or something to the same effect), to see whether the issue is with the server configuration, or with any applications you may be running.