# force www in htaccess except all subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain

my force www htaccess code is :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but i have problems with **subdomains** ex:

```
abcdef.example.com  ====> www.abcdef.example.com
```

and i want to edit code to be worked like these:

```
example.com         ===> www.example.com
abcdefg.example.com ===> abcdefg.example.com
example.co.uk       ===> www.example.co.uk
abcd.example.co.uk  ===> abcd.example.co.uk
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)

Comment: no its not .. it doesnt solve the subdomains problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.(co\.uk|com)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or more generic:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: does not work on Apache 2.4, it results in: `www.sub.domain.com`