# non-www to www. redirect AND redirect index.html to index.php

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im using mod_rewrite to direct all non-www requests to the www. url using the following code

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks


# non-www to www resolve
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.website\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

however i recently changed the index page from .html to .php and have several external links still pointing to the index.html page.

simply adding a 301 redirect results in a loop due to the above rule

```
#1 Permanent URL redirect
Redirect 301 /index.html http://www.website.co.uk/
```

How can i adapt this code to maintain a non-www redirect and also redirect index.html requests to index.php or www.website.co.uk/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your rule like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

# non-www to www resolve
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.website\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

# index.html to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=301]
```