# Htaccess Redirect: WWW + HTTPS://WWW + HTTP:// ---> HTTPS://non-www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

This has been asked a million times, but I can't seem to find the right search terms. I would like to redirect all request URIs from:

- http:// domain.com/any_string
- http:// www.domain.com/any_string
- https://www.domain.com/any_string

to

- https://domain.com/any_string

The best answer I have found was:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But that gives me a redirect loop. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Unfortunately that results in a redirect loop. Also is there a way to make this work on multiple domains - we have a staging server too (eg: `https://stage.domain.com`) and it would be great if we could use the same code on both.