# how to remove www path in Codeigniter settings

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url, url-rewriting

According to me client demand, he want to use only `http://example.com` urls in his codeinigter. in other words he want to fully ignore www from urls path. please somebody let me know, how i can set these setting in codeigniter?

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
```

i set this type url in config.php, but still www urls works.

Comment: Fully ignore means that `http://www.example.com` should not deliver the site? Can't you just remove the subdomain from the web server settings, or even the DNS server? There's nothing magical in the `www` prefix: you need to explicitly configure it in order to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)

Comment: Am I doing something wrong when I ask for clarifications like, don't know, inadvertently using offensive words because I'm not a native speaker or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, in your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

It will redirect all `www` url requests to `non-www` url.

e.g 
`http://www.yoursite/index.php/hello/world?p=123`

to
 `http://yoursite/index.php/hello/world?p=123`