# how do I make a simple redirect from www URL to no www URL using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I know this has been asked a million times, but I can't make heads or tails out of the gobbly gook answers I found when searching.  All I need is a very simple .htaccess rule where if someone accesses my site with the www, it will remove it, so http://www.example.com --> http://example.com

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write on .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Reference:[Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)