# Correct way of handling www. and non www. when working with sessions

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, no-www

Only today found out that the two are not the same site and infact copies of eachother.

The error i am currently having is i am setting on login sessions in the normal way:

```
$_SESSION['logged'] = 1;
```

This session can be received and works on

```
domain.com
```

But doesnt work when the user navigates to any:

```
www.domain.com
```

How should i handle this? I like to use absolute links for my navigation e.g:

```
http://www.domain.com/about
```

But this causes the issue of users not using www. all the time etc.

Is there a way to allow cookies to be set on both www. and non www or is there a better way of handling this? Possibly a htaccess type redirect to the non www. page everytime?

Thanks for any insight. Craig.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use both `example.com` and `www.example.com`. You should select one and redirect the other. For example if you want to use `www.example.com`, then redirect `example.com` to `www.example.com`. You can do this easily in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or in Nginx:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    return       301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

If you want to redirect `www.example.com` to `example.com`, then you can use this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Perfect! Works as expected. Quick question, if im choosing the non www. is it good practice to still keep the http:// for the rule? Or doesnt make a blind difference?

Comment: @user2921557 Added an example to my answer. There are many ways to do this, see the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www