# htaccess redirect from www to non-www

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am new to this.

Code from my .htaccess file goes like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

Redirect 301 /abc/ /abcnew/
```

I want this to redirect from www to non-www i.e., from http://www.example.com to http://example.com

I copied:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

this code from here [Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www).

I also checked in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled folder on my linux server. There "rewrite.load" this module is present.(I think this might mean that rewrite is enabled on my server, but correct me if I am wrong.)

```
Redirect 301 /abc/ /abcnew/
```

and just FYI this above code works fine(its redirecting my old links to new links).

I also tried this.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Doesn't work for me.

Please help. Thanks in advance...

Edit:

[this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/120488/redirect-url-within-apache-virtualhost/120507#120507) I found this. But not sure what should be edited. Can anyone please point out.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place `external (full) redirect` rules before internal rewrite ones and also make sure to use `mod_rewrite` rules only.

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^abc/?$ /abcnew/ [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava. I tried this code but still not working. any suggestions ?

Comment: Open Firebug and then visit `http://www.example.com` in the browser. Check in Net tab how many redirects do you get.

Comment: +1, do you think the initial slash in `/abcnew` could be causing Nits's problem?

Comment: @anubhava: hi Anubhava., I dont see any redirects in firebug. I also tried putting this code by removing abc redirect and checked, still not working.

Comment: Ok first verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not? If you get 500 error then tell me location of this .htaccess and also if there are other rules in this .htaccess as well.

Comment: yeah checked.. this .htaccess was in wrong path.. I moved it to public folder, now got it working. Thanks a lot. But still did not get why the other redirection were working..

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Location of .htaccess is very critical since rules change as per the directory it is residing in.

Answer (score 0):

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```