# how can redirect domain non-www to www in laravel 4?

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-4

Hello I try to redirect my domain name from non-www to www via .htaccess file.
My previous htaccess code was

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I replace it by the code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.forexfunction\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.forexfunction.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but i face 404 errors after replacing this code.
How can i solve my problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5262044/351330)

Answer (score 5):

This is the code which will redirect non-www request to www request.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Here is how you .htacccess file will look like.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -MultiViews
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: this will not works for me, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36811573/how-redirect-no-www-url-to-www-url-in-laravel