# how redirect no-www url to www url in laravel?

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

i had tried bellow code in my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]


    #Force www:
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

</IfModule>
```

the prblem is that, when ever i hits `example.com` it redirect me to `www.example.com`
but when i hit `example.com/ppl2016` it will redirect me to `www.example.co./index.php`

i had review this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549482/how-can-redirect-domain-non-www-to-www-in-laravel-4` but it wont help me.

Comment: i had review this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549482/how-can-redirect-domain-non-www-to-www-in-laravel-4 but it wont help me. please reopen question.

Comment: hi, now its working, it's needed to clear cache in my browser.