# How do I access my local hosted website domain with both abc.com and www.abc.com?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns, xampp

I have my website hosted using XAMPP. I have a domain name purchased through 1and1, and have the A Record pointing at my ip address. The website works just fine if I type in abc.com, but if I try www.abc.com, I get a 404 error.

I called 1and1 up and they said they wont help because they are not hosting the site. They said to make it work I have to do htaccess rewrite.

I tried looking into this, but I cannot seem to find anyone having this issue.

Any help to figure this out would be amazing!

Comment: Here is how you might do it in reverse (www.abc.com to abc.com) - I'm sure you can figure out how to do it from the code given: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do two things:
1) Create one more DNS record for `www.abc.com` pointing to the same IP address.
2) In your virtual host configurations, look for `ServerName abc.com`.  Add a server alias under server name.
`ServerAlias www.abc.com`