# .htaccess domain-independent www to non-www with piggyback home page rule

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

On https://stackoverflow.com/a/1270281/891052 there's a solution for "Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www". It makes the site 301 Redirect from www to non-www without the need of specifying the domain name.

It looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What I have tried to accomplish is to add a rule to it where /home redirects to the root.

In other words that 
http://example.com/home and 
http://www.example.com/home go to
http://example.com
regardless of the domain name.

But I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^home/?$ / [NC,L]
```

Comment: that was ridiculously easy :D