# rewrite www. to without www. in .htaccess for hostname instead of writing in the website name?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.e-innovate.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://e-innovate.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

But what i am trying to do is create a general rewrite code which i can drop into .htaccess files without having to change the domain name such as below, i dont seem to be able to get this to work, am i on the right track ?

Thanks

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)

Comment: hi i tried this already and it gives me a redirect loop

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

note that this will also get applied to subdomains.