# .htaccess redirect www to non-www not working

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I pretty much know nothing about about .htaccess editing or regex expressions. What I have done to try to make my site re-direct from `www` versions to `non-www` versions is I followed the answers posted here:

[redirect www to non-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30145779/redirect-www-to-non-www)

However, what I get is that if I enter `www.example.com`, I get:

`example.com/example.com/` and a 404 error on my site

This is my .htaccess file:

```
#Adjust default time zone 
SetEnv TZ America/Toronto

#Begin redirect www to non-www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

# Google Analytics Integration - Added by cPanel.
<IfModule mod_substitute.c>
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
Substitute "s|(<script src='/google_analytics_auto.js'></script>)?</head>|<script src='/google_analytics_auto.js'></script></head>|i"
</IfModule>
# END Google Analytics Integration
```

Can someone enlighten me on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How are you getting `example.com/example.com/` in redirected URL? Did you try clearing your browser cache?

Comment: There must be something else in your configuration files or in .htaccess. Or maybe the site is in a subdirectory and there is some problem with the directory prefix.

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

That is, check if the HTTP_HOST contains www and if so, redirect to non-www with the request_uri appended.